# Can we integrate GPT-4 with a simple flask API to generate a description for an image sent?

Tags: python, openai-api, gpt-4

just want to create an API that takes an image and gives out a json description in the format:

```
{
   "status" : "200",
   "description" : "a discription of the image in 50 words"
}
```

I tried asking this from chatgpt itself but it says here that we have to implement our own function or some other tool to generate a descriotion. all this code does is use an already existing description(gives out a description from a text input) what i need is to have it generate a description from image like the chat GPT-4 does when its given an image.

Any ML or image procecing way to achieve this would be fantastic :)

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import openai

app = Flask(__name__)

# Set your OpenAI API key here
openai.api_key = 'your-openai-api-key'

@app.route('/generate_description', methods=['POST'])
def generate_description():
    # Check if the request contains a file
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        return jsonify({'error': 'No file part'}), 400

    file = request.files['file']

    # Process the file (you may need to save it temporarily, depending on your requirements)
    # Here, we assume 'process_image' is a function to handle image processing
    image_description = process_image(file)

    # Use GPT-4 to generate a description based on the image
    try:
        response = openai.Completion.create(
            engine="text-davinci-002",  # Use the appropriate GPT-4 engine
            prompt=f"Describe the following image: {image_description}",
            max_tokens=50  # Adjust the maximum number of tokens as needed
        )
        generated_description = response.choices[0].text.strip()
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 500

    return jsonify({'description': generated_description})

def process_image(file):
    # Placeholder for image processing logic
    # You may need to use an image recognition tool or library for this step
    # Return a string representing the processed image description
    return 'a processed image description'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Please read about [mcve]. Do you really need folks who know `flask` or could you remove those aspects and improve the odds of getting an answer by actually making a ***minimal*** example without `flask`?